# Thermal runaway triggers when raising temperature amid cooldown

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, skr-mini-e3

I've noticed an interesting behavior on my Ender 3 with SKR Mini E3 mainboard and Marlin 2.0.x bugfix firmware. (*otherwise, all other hardware is entirely stock*) After the hotend/bed are commanded to cool down, e.g. after a print completes, I have to wait until after they both cool down to ambient before commanding another temperature setpoint.

If I don't do this, the printer most often triggers thermal runaway protection. (*usually citing the extruder, but also sometimes the bed*) I think this might be due to the thermal inertia in the material between the heater and thermistors, causing a 5-10 second delay in sensed temperature rise. I don't see any reason why thermal runaway should trigger; the Octoprint temperature graph looks completely normal, with no perceptible anomalies.

Is there some way to tune parameters for thermal runaway protection to alleviate this false-positive situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are ways to tune false positives. For Marlin firmware you can find these option in the [Configuration_adv.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/2.0.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h) file.

From the file itself you can read what you need to do:

> ```
>  * If you get false positives for "Thermal Runaway", increase
>  * THERMAL_PROTECTION_HYSTERESIS and/or THERMAL_PROTECTION_PERIOD
>  */
> ```

Comment: Any recommendations for how to go about increasing both settings? One before the other, increased symmetrically?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the underlying problem of this, just try to experiment with one at a time.